# How to fix "General failure" error in TPM coding

Tags: tpm

I want to use tpm nvstore for writing and reading.When program run to"Tspi_NV_Definespace",it comes "general failure".I want to find how I can solve it.

```
Tspi_Context_Create(&hContext);

Tspi_Context_Connect(hContext, NULL);//connect to local host

Tspi_Context_GetTPMObject(hContext, &hTPM);//get handle 

Tspi_GetPolicyObject(hTPM, TSS_POLICY_USAGE, &hOwnerPolicy);
Tspi_Policy_SetSecret(hOwnerPolicy, TSS_SECRET_MODE_PLAIN, strlen(secret), secret);//set secret

Tspi_Context_CreateObject(hContext, TSS_OBJECT_TYPE_NV, 0, &hNvStore);//create nvram object
Tspi_SetAttribUint32(hNvStore, TSS_TSPATTRIB_NV_INDEX, 0, 1);
Tspi_SetAttribUint32(hNvStore, TSS_TSPATTRIB_NV_PERMISSIONS, 0, TPM_NV_PER_AUTHWRITE);//permit to write


Tspi_SetAttribUint32(hNvStore, TSS_TSPATTRIB_NV_DATASIZE, 0, dataLen);

result = Tspi_NV_DefineSpace(hNvStore, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Is the TPM owned?

Comment: Sorry,I'm new to linux. Does it mean I should root before  compiling?

Comment: No, it means that ownership needs to be asserted on the TPM, at least I can't think of another reason for a general failure like you're getting. Look up how to take ownership of TPM 1.2.

Comment: Hello I try to use tpm_takeownership to get ownership,but I meet 'The tpm target command has been disabled'.Then I use tpm_clear, and I meet 'general failure' again.

Comment: Check if your BIOS offers an option to enable TPM, enable take ownership or something like that...

Comment: Thank you,but I use swtpm software by ibm. So I think I cannot enable TPM in bios.